# minitoc customisation

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I have the following in my minitoc:

```
1     One One
2     Two Two
      2.1     Two Point One
      2.2     Two Point two
```

I wonder if there is a way to reduce the space after the section and subsection numbers to have something like:

```
1  One One
2  Two Two
   2.1  Two Point One
   2.2  Two Point two
```

A MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\dominitoc

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\minitoc

\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One Two}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can show your recent efforts in form of a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: I have just added a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following in my file and it works as expected.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2em}
```